# Matching and adding column from data frame

Tags: r, merge, match

**QUESTION**

How I can add column which values are selected by two factors and one of these is a rows names from the other data frame?

**EXAMPLE DATA**

I have the following data frame:

```
Country, Year, Q1          
Portugal, 2004, Yes
Portugal, 2005, Yes 
Portugal, 2008, No  
UK, 2006, Yes 
UK, 2008, No 
France, 2004, No
```

I want to add a column from other data frame;

```
Country, 2004,2005,2006,...
Portugal,0.15,0.25,0.14,0.21,...
Spain,0.16,0.26,0.14,0.16,...
UK,0.17,0.23,0.18,0.17,...
France,0.15,0.26,0.11,0.20,...
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

And get a data frame look like this;

```
Country, Year, Q1 , Q2         
Portugal, 2004, Yes, 0.15
Portugal, 2005, Yes, 0.25
Portugal, 2006, No , 0.14
UK, 2005, Yes , 0.23
UK, 2006, No , 0.18
France, 2004, No, 0.15
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tidyr and dplyr libraries:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

# convert df2 to df2_long format
df2_long <- 
  df2 %>%
  gather( Year, Value, -Country, convert = TRUE  )

# join df1 with df2
df1 %>%
  left_join( df2_long, by = c("Country", "Year"))
```

The result:

```
   Country Year  Q1 Value
1 Portugal 2004 Yes  0.15
2 Portugal 2005 Yes  0.25
3 Portugal 2008  No    NA
4       UK 2006 Yes  0.18
5       UK 2008  No    NA
6   France 2004  No  0.15
```

The input data I used:

```
df1 <- 
  structure(list(Country = c("Portugal", "Portugal", "Portugal", 
  "UK", "UK", "France"), Year = c(2004L, 2005L, 2008L, 2006L, 2008L, 
  2004L), Q1 = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "No", "No")), 
  .Names = c("Country", 
  "Year", "Q1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

df2 <-
  structure(list(Country = c("Portugal", "Spain", "UK", "France"
  ), `2004` = c(0.15, 0.16, 0.17, 0.15), `2005` = c(0.25, 0.26, 
  0.23, 0.26), `2006` = c(0.14, 0.14, 0.18, 0.11)), .Names = c("Country", 
  "2004", "2005", "2006"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use merge() function

merge(x, y, by = intersect(names(x), names(y))

for example:

```
l <- c(1,2,3); d <- c("a","b","c");  a <- data.frame(col1=l, col2=d)
l <- c(1,2,3); d <- c("a2","b2","c2");  b <- data.frame(col1=l, col2=d)
```

and then 
    merge(a,b,by="col1")

you'll get:

```
col1 col2.x col2.y
1    1      a     a2
2    2      b     b2
3    3      c     c2
```